# Search in dijit.Tree

Tags: dojo, dijit.tree

In one of my projects I use a dijit.Tree control. I need to add a search to the tree and show only those nodes/leafs which have the searched term in them. However I can't seem to figure out how that can be achieved. Could anybody please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im not entirely sure that your question entirely but it should give hint whereas to go.

Lets use reference documentation example as offset, there is 1) a store 2) a model and 3) the tree

```
    var store = new ItemFileReadStore({
        url: "{{dataUrl}}/dijit/tests/_data/countries.json"
    });

    var treeModel = new ForestStoreModel({
        store: store,
        query: {"type": "continent"}, // note, this bit
        rootId: "root",
        rootLabel: "Continents",
        childrenAttrs: ["children"]
    });

    new Tree({
        model: treeModel
    }, "treeOne");
```

Interpret the above as such; You have loaded all known countries and continents but 'user' has selected only to show continents by using query on the model - and the hierachy is then represented in a tree structure.

You want a textbox with searching capeabilities, so we hook into onChange

```
    new dijit.form.TextBox({
        onChange: function() {
              ...
        }
    });
```

First bit, getting variables

```
var searchByName = this.get("value");
var oQuery = treeModel.query;
```

Next, set a new query on the model - preserving the old ones with an object mixin

```
treeModel.query = dojo.mixin(oQuery, { name: '*'+searchByName+'*' });
```

Last, notify the model and its tree that changes has occurred - and requery the visible items.

```
treeModel._requeryTop();
```

**NB** If the top-level item (for ForestModel) is not visible, none of its child elements will show, even if the search-string matches those. (Examplewise, Alabama is not shown if US Continent is not matched by query)

*EDIT*

As OP has the agenda to go by the 'NB', this may not fit needs 100% but its what dojo offers with dijit.Tree.. As it will get rather a lengthy process to recode the model/store queries to include parentbranches up until root i will not do this here - but there are a few tricks still ;)

```
var tree = new dijit.Tree( {
   /**
    * Since TreeNode has a getParent() method, this abstraction could be useful
    * It sets the dijit.reqistry id into the item-data, so one l8r can get parent items
    * which otherwise only can be found by iterating everything in store, looking for item in the parent.children
    *
   */
   onLoad : function() {
       this.forAllNodes(function(node) {
            // TreeNode.item <-- > store.items hookup
            node.item._NID = node.domNode.id
       });
   },
   /* recursive iteration over TreeNode's
    * Carefull, not to make (too many) recursive calls in the callback function..
    * fun_ptr : function(TreeNode) { ... }
   */
   forAllNodes : function(parentTreeNode, fun_ptr) {
        parentTreeNode.getChildren().forEach(function(n) {
             fun_ptr(n);
             if(n.item.children) {
                 n.tree.forAllNodes(fun_ptr);
             }
        })
   }
});
```

(non-tested, but might just work) Example:

```
// var 'tree' is your tree, extended with
tree.forAllNodes = function(parentTreeNode, fun_ptr) {
        parentTreeNode.getChildren().forEach(function(n) {
             fun_ptr(n);
             if(n.item.children) {
                 n.tree.forAllNodes(fun_ptr);
             }
        })
};
// before anything, but the 'match-all' query, run this once
tree.forAllNodes(tree.rootNode, function(node) {
    // TreeNode.item <-- > store.items hookup
    node.item._NID = node.domNode.id
});

// hopefully, this in end contains top-level items
var branchesToShow = [] 

// run fetch every search (TextBox.onChange) with value in query
tree.model.store.fetch(query:{name:'Abc*'}, onComplete(function(items) {
   var TreeNode = null;
   dojo.forEach(items, function(item) {
       TreeNode = dijit.byId(item._NID+'');
       while(TreeNode.getParent() 
             && typeof TreeNode.getParent().item._RI == 'undefined') {
          TreeNode = TreeNode.getParent();
       }
       branchesToShow.push(TreeNode.item);
   });
}});

// Now... If a success, try updating the model via following
tree.model.onChildrenChange(tree.model.root, branchesToShow);
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your help! The case is that in my original definition of the tree model I have "query: {"type": "parent"}" while when searching I need to get the query based on the name of both nodes and leafs. In this current case it does not return any nodes when I search by the name of a leaf.

Comment: the store query itself will return results.. only, the tree cannot show them since their the branch of a leaf has been 'cut off', i.e. higher level item values does not match query. you would need to query the store and then manually iterate children nodes to set a full branch visible/hidden

Comment: it will get rather messy... model does not doubly-link the items so children doesnt know who their parents are

Comment: So, it's basically impossible?

Comment: nothing is impossible :p  but that being said I would suggest setting up a FilteringSelect input field, using the same store - other then spending 3-4 hours plus coding that implementation. Or make `store.fetch({query:{namebasedonly:'??'}, onComplete:function(items) { items...ids...tree...nodes..toggle highlight CSS if item match } });` functionality

Comment: take another look, it may or may not run